# Contoso University Network error on context.Database.EnsureCreated()

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, localdb

i am currently working on the Contoso University project with the razor pages.
I just met 1 problem on my way and it happens when i initialize the migrations in the `Program.cs`

For a strange reason it seems like the app cannot connect to the local database.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ContosoUniversity.Data;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext")));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{ 
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    // DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

and the error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 50 - Local
```

Everything. I just need a fix for this project.

Comment: The error message tells you to check your connection string. Is it in your appSettings file and is it correct?

Comment: I followed all the steps from the tutorial, so all the settings should be right.  My guess is that when i do the scaffolding is the problem. For some reason it doesn't update the program.cs correctly. It shows a ?? Throw exemption .... I will upload a screen shot later on.

Comment: i get this code when i do the scaffolding: options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'SchoolContext' not found.")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like i solved the problem.

First follow this fix on microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

What i did after the steps from above:

```
> deleted register loging details from regedit.msc

> installed server express 2019

> open cmd -> sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB -> sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB -> sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `appsettings.json` if it contains such **key** with value like below:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SchoolContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

**Note:** The server and database name depends on yourself.  And the key name must contains `ConnectionStrings`, check the spelling also.

**Update:**

If still not working, try to manually add the following code to your **DbContext** class:

```
public class YourDbContext: DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<MvcProjContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }
    //....
}
```

**Update2:**

Or just hard-coded connection string like below:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"));
```

If still not working, pls make sure that you have an instance named `MSSQLLocalDB`. To check, run command `sqllocaldb info` in `Package Manager Console`. If you do not have that instance, you will need either to create it (sqllocaldb create mssqllocaldb) or to change your connection string to point at an instance that you do have.

Comment: i have: `"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SchoolContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity.Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }`                   So the connection to the local database is right.

Comment: Hi @BorisIonut, pls try to manually add the code in my updated answer and check if it makes error or not.

Comment: Same problem. It just drops me the same error. I replaced DataBaseName with ContosoUniversity from your code and still the same thing...

Comment: Hi @BorisIonut, if you **hard-coded** the connection string still make no sense, maybe you need check if you have an instance named `MSSQLLocalDB`. If all the options still not working, maybe share your code without any personal message/data to giuhub and share with us may be helpful...

Comment: i will post my code to github and i will post it for you later on today.

Comment: Hi @BorisIonut, Any way check my updated answer first.

Comment: there's the github [link](https://github.com/Antaurix/ContosoUniversity). I checked your updated answer and when i did the scaffolding it already did the steps that you proposed.

Comment: I just did the steps on my other laptop and is running fine. I saw that VS2022 is asking for SSL certificate. i accepted it on the other laptop and when i did the scaffolding to replace _context.Student with _context.Students it shows me 8 instances and the code was runing. Instead, on this laptop it showed me 13 instances. I think there's a problem with the SSL certificate.